# Bot Framework with singleton class

Tags: c#, singleton, botframework

I am doing a proactive bot with the resumption cookie.

I have 1 singleton class which is a list of objects. where I have the singleton defined like:

```
public static MyObj instance = new MyObj();

public List<Objects> thename = null;
public int count { get; set; }

public static MyObj Instance
{
        get
        {
           return instance;
        }
}
```

then I have the conversationStarter class:

```
public class ConversationStarter
    {

        public static string resumptionCookie;

        public static async Task Resume()
        {
            var message = ResumptionCookie.GZipDeserialize(resumptionCookie).GetMessage();
            var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
                await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

                //interrupt the stack
                var dialog = new AlarmDialog();
                task.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);


                task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

                //flush dialog stack
                await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the RootDialog I have a timer that will call a new Dialog every x seconds.
In that dialog I do:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class NewDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Myobj objList;

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            objList= Myobj.Instance;


            PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.AfterSelectOption, 
                new string[] { "Stay in this survey", "Get back to where I was" },
                "Hello, you're in the survey dialog. Please pick one of these options");

        }

        private async Task AfterSelectOption(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {

            if ((await result) == "Get back to where I was")
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Great, back to the original conversation!");
                context.Done(String.Empty); //Finish this dialog
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync("I'm still on the survey until you tell me to stop");
                PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.AfterSelectOption, new string[] { "Stay in this survey", "Get back to where I was" }, "Hello, you're in the survey dialog. Please pick one of these options");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I access the instance of MyObj in the NewDialog i am getting the following exception int ConversationStarter:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException: 'invalid need: expected Wait, have None'
```

at the line:

```
 task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

If I don't try to access my singleton class everything goes smoothly. Is it not possible to use a singleton class like this?

Comment: Is your singleton class serializable?

Comment: It is serializable

Comment: Have you checked out this sample: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to implement a pro-active bot. If I'm not mistaken by calling the PollAsync method you are interrupting the dialog stack without giving it a point to resume from.

I think you should have a look at [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot). It has the same goal as your bot but it uses Autofac. More specifically the [ExternalEvents](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot/Models/ExternalEvent.cs) class. Using a IOC container is also better then just implementing a Singleton.